# How to run a file containing SBCL Lisp code on the command line

Tags: linux, command-line, lisp, sbcl

I just installed SBCL (on a Rapberry PI) using:

```
pi# apt install sbcl
```

I noticed that, unlike with clisp, putting:

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl
```

at the top does not allow me to run a Lisp script file from the command line.

So my question is, once my Lisp code is written and stored in a file called `test`,
what do I need to do - and how - (adding something to the file? Or compile it? Or ....) to be able to run it from the command line?

For a bit more details:

Here is what happens in the terminal:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/SBCL $ cat test
#!/usr/bin/sbcl

(defun HI()
(let (vx 0)
(setf vx (+ (* 3 5) (mod 27 7)))
(format t "~a~%" vx)
))

(HI)

pi@raspberrypi:~/SBCL $ ls -l test 
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 104 Dec  2 05:41 test
pi@raspberrypi:~/SBCL $ ./test 
This is SBCL 2.2.9.debian, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.
*
```

Comment: Generally speaking, `#!/usr/bin/sbcl` should work. Did you `chmod +x myLispScript`? Are there any error messages when you try to run your script with the "she-bang"? Did you confirm that `/usr/bin/sbcl` is where the cmd was installed? `type sbcl` will show you. What does `man sbcl` reveal?  (I'm not a lisp person, so don't know about compiling or other.) Good luck.

Comment: @shellter. I just added to the post what happens in the terminal. Please take a look.
You will se the results of the command: cat, ls -l and ./test

Comment: It seems to be honoring the `#!/usr/bin/sbcl`. The `awk` language requires `#!/bin/awk -f` to read the text of the file it is part of. Try that (`-f`) or look at the man page and see what is required to name a program from the cmd line like `/usr/bin/sbcl -f myScript` and use that after the "she-bang" (`-F` ??) . Just relying on std-practices here, so good luck. Going to bed and I think I'm out of ideas now. Good luck.

Comment: The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sbcl) suggests `--script` rather than `-f`

Comment: (As an aside, just like in other languages, you would conventionally use indentation to make the structure of your `defun`  legible to a human reader.)

Comment: @tripleee. Yes that worked !
You are totally right about the indentation. Here it is just a test. The inside was indignificant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual has a [brief section about this.](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Shebang-Scripts)

```
#!/usr/bin/sbcl --script

(your Lisp code here)
```

Of course, you'd have to know the term [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to know to look for this.